# Como posso abreviar um nome para 2 palavras, ignorando (de, da, dos, das)?

Tags: php, string

Tenho uma tabela de usuários no sistema onde o nome completo do usuário é registrado.
Porém,  na hora de exibir esses nomes no sistema, devo utilizar apenas duas palavras do nome dessa pessoa para exibir. E quando as palavras `das`, `dos`, `da`, `do` e `de` aparecem, eu preciso que essas palavras sejam ignoradas o próximo nome seja capturado. Mas sempre deve se exibir apenas 2 palavras do nome da pessoa.

Exemplos:

```
 'Márcio da Silva da Costa' => 'Márcio Silva'
 'Lucas Oliveira Xavier'    => 'Lucas Oliveira'
 'Wallace de Souza'         => 'Wallace Souza'
```

Como posso fazer isso em PHP?

Atualmente tenho um código que faz isso, mas gostaria de algo mais simples do que isso:

```
function nameSlice($name, $int = 2)
{
    $ignore = array('e', 'de', 'da', 'do', 'dos', 'das', 'a', 'le');

    $sliceName = explode(' ', $name);

    foreach ($sliceName as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array(strtolower($value), $ignore) && $int != $key) {
            $int++;
        }
    }

    $sliceName = array_slice(array_filter($sliceName), 0, $int);

    if (in_array(strtolower(end($sliceName)), $ignore, true)) {
        array_pop($sliceName);
    }

    return implode(' ', $sliceName);
}
```

Comment: O que já fez? :D Tem certeza que vai ignorar o último nome? Ele costuma ser o mais importante. Mas nem sempre. Então automatizar isto pode produzir resultados inúteis.

Comment: Exigências do meu Chefe, @bigown!

Comment: @bigown, deu pra perceber que tem uma gambiarra no meu código, né. Essa era a época que eu criava uma classe chamada `Util` e criava um tanto de método estático nela.

Comment: Gambiarra é normal, se der tempo, eu dou uma olhada.

Comment: Só deve obter o nome e o primeiro sobrenome? Ou o último?

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade, como no exemplo mostrado na pergunta. Primeiro e o segundo. Se a segunda palavra for `de|das?|dos?`, então ignoramos essa palavra e pulamos pra próxima.

Comment: @bigown, consegui isso http://ideone.com/NdLDPX

Comment: Acho que essa pergunta foi boa pra mim. Me forçou a refatorar recursos do sistemas (que eu mesmo fiz) que estão ultrapassados. O primeiro passo para a cura é admitir o problema. Nesse caso, eu admito a minha gambiarra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um método simples de expressão regular já irá resolve o seu problema:

```
function removeDaDeDiDoDu($name) {
           $name = preg_replace('/\s(d[A-z]{1,2}|a(.){1,2}?|e(.){1,2}?|le{1}|[A-z.]{1,2}\s)/i',' ',$name);
           return preg_replace('/\s+/i',' ', $name);
}
```

Aqui um exemplo funcionando:
**http://ideone.com/ow9LSN**

Agora se você quer só dois nomes, basta pegar o primeiro e o último:

```
$nome = 'Wallace de Souza Vizerra';
$allNames = explode(' ', $nome);
$nome = $allNames[0].' '.$allNames[count($allNames)-1];
echo $nome;
```

Aqui o exemplo: **http://ideone.com/yVBZhx**

Comment: Curti a sua função. Funcionou. O único problema é que em `'wallace de soza vizerra'` ele converte para `'wallace  souza vizerra'` com dois espaços onde havia o `de|da|do`

Comment: Sim, removi os espaços duplos, veja lá.

Comment: Se quiser melhorar a expressão, aqui está o caminho: http://regexr.com/3bt9u

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Só uma dica. `\s\s+` não é necessário, apenas `\s+`.

Comment: fato. o + já faz isso